# proper way jquery animate opacity, fade, & slide up page load effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, onload

this is the first time I've actually made my own Jquery script from scratch, cause I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.  My code works how I want it to, although I don't know if I did it correctly.  Just something about it is screaming to me although it works, I didn't do it properly.  So I figured I would share what I have and see what you guys had to offer as a better way to accomplish this.

The Jquery I came up with is

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".overlay").animate({
    opacity: .5,
    height: "0"
}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).remove()
})
});
$(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".somediv").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 600)
}, 600)
})
```

I have ran it though a js compressor which removed the ;'s, and then through a "beautifier" for readability, but it still seems to work and really I'm not even too sure how important those are in js lol, I'm a CSS guy and i know in CSS the last ; is not required... so figured I'd leave them out since it's working.

I set up an example of this in action [Here: JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gixovoqo/2/)

so if anyone has any suggestions on my code as this being my first real attempt at JQuery I would love some feedback =)

Comment: You're correct about the `;`. The last one is not needed in jQuery. However this question seems to be off-topic, since you apparently don't have a specific programming problem, but want a code review, right?

Comment: Well the question is did i go about this correctly, somethings telling me even though it works, I didn't do it properly.

Comment: Maybe consider posting this in codereview.exchange?

Comment: what? I didn't even know there was one lol, got a link?

Comment: nvm found it, that'll come in handy =)

Comment: You say you're a css guy, why didn't you just do it in css?

Comment: cause to my knowledge i cant get this SAME effect with pure css, and I already implement JQ on my site... so why not use JQ...

Comment: just wanted to share that i actually did achieve this in pure css =)  thanks for the suggestions guys!
simple demo http://jsbin.com/vafapibu/1/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: read through the comments.... and i do state it in my OP, I stated my question... I got my answer, I for one don't think it's off topic to ask if I did some JQ properly but either way this has been answered thanks to Ian for understanding what I was wondering, who showed me how I can kill a function and shorten my code.  Also thanks to Jimmy for pointing me to a new exchange for future reference.  Yes this was semi wanting reviewed, but I was also curious on how I could shorten it up properly... so wouldn't that make it acceptable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did isn't wrong, but there is a delay function you could use here.

```
$(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".somediv").animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 600)
}, 600)
})
```

would become

```
$(function() {
    $(".somediv").delay(600).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 600)
})
```

Both will work and are equally relevant code, delay is just a shortcut to what you did. What I would recommend however is using CSS3 animation rather than JQuery. It's smoother, and degrades more gracefully if for some reason JQuery can't load or JS is off or errors out. Granted these are rare issues but I would still use CSS because it's built into the browser and you can access hardware acceleration if you initiate it with tanslateZ(0). Then use JQuery to possibly add a class on window load or even use it for your delay.

Comment: thanks for the feedback I was looking for, I didn't know exactly why, but I had a feeling there were too many functions.  As for the css, to my knowledge I wouldn't be able to achieve this same effect with transitions and animations.  I'll play around with those but this will work for now =)  Plus I already use JQ site wide anyway, so it works ...for now lol